# index match where data is in two Google Sheet tabs

Tags: google-sheets, sum, match, index-match

I have a Google Sheet containing 2 tabs; tab1 and tab2

tab1 contents:

```
      A        B       C        D       E       F       G
 1  Group    Score    Pete     Bob    John    Sarah   David  
 2  A                 TRUE            TRUE
 3  B                         TRUE    TRUE             TRUE
 4  C                                 TRUE     TRUE
```

tab2 contents:

```
       A         B
   1 Pete       18
   2 John       25
   3 David       5
   4 Sarah       5
   5 Bob         8
```

*The two columns in tab2 have named ranges; `each_name` and `name_points`

I am trying to use `INDEX` `MATCH` to get the `Score` sum, which is the total of points allocated to each person as shown in tab2. However, the sum in the `Score` column in tab1 should only add points of persons with TRUE in their column

The desired output would therefore be:

```
      A        B       C        D       E       F       G
 1  Group    Score    Pete     Bob    John    Sarah   David  
 2  A           43    TRUE            TRUE
 3  B           38            TRUE    TRUE             TRUE
 4  C           13                    TRUE     TRUE
```

However, the formula that I've built so far, only produces `0`

`B2 = SUMIF(name_points,each_name,INDEX(C$1:G$1,0,MATCH(TRUE,C$2:G$2,0)))`

`B3 = SUMIF(name_points,each_name,INDEX(C$1:G$1,0,MATCH(TRUE,C$3:G$3,0)))`

`B4 = SUMIF(name_points,each_name,INDEX(C$1:G$1,0,MATCH(TRUE,C$4:G$4,0)))`

Comment: Take care not to spam tags. Your question is specifically about google sheets, not excel.

Comment: note taken - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try, in B2 of Sheet1

```
=sum(arrayformula(vlookup(query(transpose({$C$1:$G$1;C2:G2}),"select Col1 where Col2=TRUE",0),Sheet2!A:B,2,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Cheers Mike, seems that the syntax in Google Sheets is slightly different from Excel

Comment: yes ... do you want a formula for excel or google sheets ?

Comment: In the past I had used excel, but now I am using Google Sheets and your formulae works in it - out of interest, how would it look as an excel formula

Comment: I was an Excel expert. Since using Google Sheet, I use the most accurate solution for GS.